# Many to many relationship returns empty set

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, many-to-many

I have a following table structure in my existing database :
`tbl_Grzyby (ID, Nazwa, ...)`  - main table,
`tblk_TypGrzyba (ID, TypGrzyba, OrderNo)` - lookup table,
`tblm_TypGrzyba (ID_Grzyb, ID_TypGrzyba)` (many-to-many table).

I've created a `grzyby` Eloquent model class, which has a custom property, defined as:

```
class grzyby extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tbl_Grzyby';

    public function typ_grzyba() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Lookups\typ_grzyba', 'tblm_TypGrzyba','ID_Grzyb', 'ID_TypGrzyba');
    }

}
```

I've also created the lookup table model, defined as:

```
class typ_grzyba extends Model {
    protected $table = 'tblk_TypGrzyba';

    public function grzyby() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\grzyby', 'tblm_TypGrzyba','ID_Grzyb', 'ID_TypGrzyba');
    }

}
```

When I try with tinker to get record from main with ID=67, like:

```
$main_record=\App\grzyby::where('ID',67)->first();
```

it returns me all the details for that record fine. Returning all lookups runs also fine:

```
$types = \App\Lookups\typ_grzyba::all();
```

However, if I try to do the following:

```
$main_record_types = $main_record->typ_grzyba;
```

tinker returns me an empty collection, despite record existing in the many to many table: [image: record EXISTS in the many-to-many table]

When I run the query log it outputs me following SQL query:

```
select `tblk_TypGrzyba`.*, `tblm_TypGrzyba`.`ID_Grzyb` as `pivot_ID_Grzyb`, `tblm_TypGrzyba`.`ID_TypGrzyba` as `pivot_ID_TypGrzyba` from `tblk_TypGrzyba` inner join `tblm_TypGrzyba` on `tblk_TypGrzyba`.`id` = `tblm_TypGrzyba`.`ID_TypGrzyba` where `tblm_TypGrzyba`.`ID_Grzyb` is null
```

If I run that query against the database it returns me empty result, however, if I change the where clause manually to

```
where `tblm_TypGrzyba`.`ID_Grzyb` = 67
```

I'm getting the expected results in phpMyAdmin.

What's the reason of it and how I can fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add the `primaryKey` overrride because I was using uppercase for the ID field and then **restart** tinker.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up your foreign key defintion in your relationships. You wrote this twice:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('\App\grzyby', 'tblm_TypGrzyba','ID_Grzyb', 'ID_TypGrzyba');
```

I assume copy pasting? in the second model, justt swap the foreign key. Foreign key of the current model comes first.

In typ_grzyba model, do

```
public function grzyby() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\grzyby', 'tblm_TypGrzyba', 'ID_TypGrzyba', 'ID_Grzyb');
}
```

Comment: Query still shows ``tblm_TypGrzyba`.`ID_Grzyb` is null` ?

Comment: Yes, it does, unfortunately.

Comment: What about namespacing? Just double check your namespaces are correct. Sometimes you have `Lookups` in your namespace and sometimes, not. Maybe it's all good.

Comment: Namespaces seems to be fine, getting the `model::all()` records is working fine, it's just that many to many relationship which is wrong